# HOW CAN I HIDE A FORM BASED ON USER ROLE OR PRIVILEGE PHP

Tags: php, forms, middleware

Please how can I hide a form or input field based on the user role or privilege using PHP.
is it possible to do that using sessions and if so, how?

Comment: you can do this by storing the user role in session or fetch it on runtime where your form is located and make simple if condition to show or hide that element.
Or you can also make an global function which checks the role from session and write whole element html if condition is true and u can use that code every where in your system so if come changes occured you just have to change in one place.

Comment: Thank you Hammad, please can you show me  an example

Comment: We are not here to do your homework. Pls tell the problem statement that you face

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function return_html(){
$role = $_SESSION['role'];
$approved_role=[1,2];
  if(in_array($role ,$approved_role)){
   echo '<button>Add New</button>';
   }

}
```

use this function in your form it will be global and you can also defined permission in your db and fetch it inside the function and then make the condition.